# How to prevent MySQL user-defined variables collision

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

I have a node.js server that uses node-mysql connection pool to query MySQL database.

I need to make `SELECT` query that uses a user-defined variable to add a sum of previous rows. Before the query, I `SET` the variable to initialize it to 0.

```
SET @sum:=0;
SELECT *, @sum := @sum + `value` AS SUM FROM `table`;
```

The query works as expected but I'm worried what will happen if there are multiple requests to my node server at the same time. The server will make multiple queries. Will they collide and affect each other, each incrementing the same variable? And if yes, how can I prevent this?

The best case scenario would be to limit the scope of the variable just to the one `SELECT` query. That would allow me to remove the `SET` statement and wrap `@sum` in `ISNULL`. So the result would be

```
SELECT *, @sum := ISNULL(@sum,0) + `value` AS SUM FROM `table`;
```

But I don't know how to limit the scope so at the end of this query `@sum` is left at the end value and for the next query, it's not `null` and so it doesn't increment from 0 again.

Anyway, I can just keep the `SET` but need to make sure multiple queries using the same connection don't affect each other. I don't know how exactly does MySQL process queries so maybe this will not even be an issue but I need to be sure.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to worry about different queries incrementing the same number.  The different queries are running in different threads or processes, and it requires a bit of work to get them to share data.

However, you can write the query using only a single statement:

```
SELECT t.*, @sum := @sum + `value` AS SUM
FROM `table` t CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT @sum := 0) params;
```

MySQL does guarantee that the `FROM` clause is evaluated before the `SELECT`, so this initializes the variable before it is used.